# OpenGL shadows without shadow mapping

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, glsl, lwjgl

I have been struggling with point light shadow mapping in 3D with OpenGL using the LWJGL for some time, especially because it's difficult to follow ultra-specific tutorials written for other languages! However, I have been asking myself whether it would be possible to create the illusion of shadows by setting the radius of a point light to the closest distance to a fragment in a certain direction. So, basically the opposite of shadow mapping, but by using per-pixel lighting you could achieve perfect shadows. Is there a term for this kind of lighting? If not, how do I set the radius of a light in only one direction (maybe in GLSL)?

Answer (score 0):

Point lights don't have a radius (they are just points, used for calculating the local illumination of the fragment processed)

OpenGL has no objects (i.e. models), so whatever you think this might do: It doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, by radius I meant distance from the light to the fragment. I know that you can control this using GLSL, but I only know how to change the radius of the entire light at once. (I also changed "object" to "fragment," that was my inner Java speaking)

Comment: I am not sure why you downvoted my question. It is harmless, not unclear, and not unhelpful. It also shows that I have done research.

Comment: @L3R5: I didn't downvote it, somebody else did. But your question is poorly researched nonetheless, which I suspect why that downvote.

Comment: @L3R5: Well, OpenGL is a **drawing** API (I have to restate that again and againg). It draws a point, line or triangle and once the pixel arrives on the framebuffer it already forget about what it did. So modifying a lights properties per the fragment has no effect on the rest of the scene. Shadows however emerge from the geometrical iteraction of at least two pieces of geometry in the scene. OpenGL by itself can not do it, no matter which tricks you try to employ locally. You have to add some kind of memory, that allows to look up the geometry of the whole scene at drawing time.

Comment: @L3R5: In case of shadow mapping the shadow map provides information about the scene's geometry as seen from the light. In the case of stencil volume shadows, by a combination of drawing silhouettes into the stencil buffer the same global geometrical information is produced, but encoded in a different fashion.

Comment: That's what a shadow map is, right? But in a shadow map, you add the shadows. I was thinking OpenGL would draw in the light, if you will.

Comment: @L3R5: No. Technically OpenGL doesn't even know what a "light" is; in old fixed pipeline OpenGL there were lights, but effectively these were just a point in space and a direction and a rather simple illumination model would use the "lights" position to determine a vertex color at each vertex and then this would just get interpolated. A shadow map by itself is not a shadow. It's a mapping that relates a ray direction from the light into the scene to the distance of the first opaque surface that ray hits. The actual shadow is created by testing if a drawn fragment lies behind that surface.

Comment: @L3R5: Here's a nice video explaining how shadow mapping works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EsccgeUpdsM

Comment: By "if you will," that is exactly what I was referring to. Thank you for the video!